# Is there any way to enforce uniqueness among elements of a "character varying[]" field in postgresql(v14)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table "records" that has a field "tags". The two tables have a mamy-to-many relationship and each keeps a field of "character varying[]" of the ids of the other table.

How can I ensure that the field itself has no duplicate elements?

Comment: Post your table definitions and relationships.

Comment: records (id PK, name, tag_ids)
sales (id PK, name, record_ids)

Comment: Do not store arrays. Correctly normalize your data, an array violates 1st normal form.

Comment: @Belayer , using junction tables doesn't suit my use case as it would decimate performance. Also, I personally think normalization is sometimes overrated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (Postgresql 14), there is no way of doing this via the database constraints.
The workaround I used was intercepting the would-be duplicate elements during the INSERT or UPDATE operations